# Can I plot a function in terms of its derivatives?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, functions

I have sign conditions on the partial derivatives of a function of two variables $f(x,y)$ and its cross-derivative, but I do not know the function itself. Can I visualise a prototype of such function?

Comment: example?${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an elliptic and a hyperbolic paraboloids:

```
Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 5], Boxed -> False,
  Axes -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Pink, Specularity[White, 50], Opacity[0.8]]]
Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 5], Boxed -> False,
  Axes -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Pink, Specularity[White, 50], Opacity[0.8]]]
```

[image]
[image]